# MSVC: Compiler bug on seemingly trivial C code?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

Here's a simple, [45 line console application](http://pastie.org/2030069) that reproduces the bug on my Win XP 32-bit system.

The relevant parts:

`input_watcher_wndproc` belongs to a window that was set-up via RegisterRawInputDevices to watch raw keyboard input events.

```
  LRESULT APIENTRY
  input_watcher_wndproc(HWND hwnd, UINT umsg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
    switch(umsg) {
    case WM_INPUT:
      analyze_raw_input((HRAWINPUT)lparam);
      DefWindowProc(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam);
      return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam);
  }

  void analyze_raw_input(HRAWINPUT raw_input) {
    RAWINPUTHEADER header;
    UINT size;
    GetRawInputData(raw_input, RID_HEADER, &header, &size, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
    printf("raw input device handle: %d\n", header.hDevice);
  }
```

When compiled with MSVC 9 or 10, the program always incorrectly reports the device handle to be "1".

However, if I apply some seemingly non-functional changes, like transforming the switch-statement into an if-statement...

```
    if (umsg == WM_INPUT) {
      analyze_raw_input((HRAWINPUT)lparam);
      DefWindowProc(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam);
      return 0;
    }
```

... or when adding an arbitrary instruction before the call to `analyze_raw_input` ...

```
  switch(umsg) {
   case WM_INPUT:
     puts("foo");
     analyze_raw_input((HRAWINPUT)lparam);
     DefWindowProc(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam);
     return 0;
   }
```

...the code runs fine and outputs the corrent device handle.

Here's the modified, working [source code](http://pastie.org/2030052), with just the print statement added.

Any ideas what might cause this behaviour?

Comment: Try initializing size to be sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER) before calling GetRawInputData

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I can't believe I missed this. Where can I learn more about what's going on behind the scenes of such a bug?

Comment: Whenever adding or moving code changes behavior, I always initially suspect initialization or memory trampling.  When I looked at the doc for [GetRawInputData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I saw that pcbSize was __inout and that size was not initialized so....

Comment: @ribram: Good eyes.  You should make that an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to initialize 'size' to be sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER) before calling GetRawInputData since this is an __inout parameter.

Comment: And check the return values of function calls like GetRawInputData, which will help you find errors like this.